# Getting innerHTML of PRE tag with Regular Expression (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this HTML string.

```
some text <pre>01     02     bb      67
02     g2     cc      67<br />
<b>03     32     dd      67</b>
04     q2     ee      67</pre> some text
```

I need a javascript regex to get the text/html inside the PRE tag and manipulate it.
It's pure text, no DOM manipulation here.

P.s. Sorry for my english.

Comment: If there is no DOM , there is no dhtml

Comment: the `<center>` cannot hold, it is too late...

Comment: I don't care how simple your HTML string is, [you can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: If you want a RegEx solution, you have provide very solid patterns. If a piece of text is always supplied in the same format, then RegExps can be used. Otherwise, you might consider using DOM manipulation instead of a RegExp.

Comment: What specific manipulation do you want to do on it?  We can't help with the regex without knowing what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can get the contents of the `pre` tag using javascript's [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method:

```
var preContents = myHTMLString.match(/<pre>.*?<\/pre>/ims).substr(5, -6);
```

That searches for a `pre` tag, the contents, and the closing `pre` tag, then removes the opening and closing `pre` tags, and stores the contents in the preContents variable.

To manipulate it, you could then edit preContents to suit your needs and use javascript's [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to change the contents:

```
myHTMLString = myHTMLString.replace(/<pre>.*?<\/pre>/ims, '<pre>' + manipulatedPreContents + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Its a string, and i need replace the inner text with a lot of manipulation. Something like this -> str.replace(/<pre>.*?<\/pre>/ig, function($1){   
    return $1.replace(/<br \/>/g, '\r\n');
});

Comment: If you stick `(` `)`s around `.*?` then it creates a group for the match. Meaning you don't need to remove the `pre` tags with `substr`.